# React Responsive Design Issue with Fixed Positioning

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tailwind-css

I'm currently facing an issue with a React application I'm working on. I've built a website using React where I have a component called CartMenu which is used within another component called Products.

The problem arises when using the developer tools in my browser and selecting a screen with 'Dimensions: responsive'. I can see a button in the page

[image]

but when I use the resolution of devices like iPhone, Samsung, or iPad, the bottom part of the screen is not visible.

[image]

```
  return (
    <div className=''>
        <div className={`absolute ${!props.isCartDisplayed ? "hidden" : "flex flex-col"} bg-black bg-opacity-70 w-full top-0 left-0 bottom-[-200px] z-9`}
             onClick={props.toggleCart}
        > 
        </div>
        <div className={`absolute ${!props.isCartDisplayed ? "hidden" : "flex flex-col"} flex justify-between h-[100vh] bg-white w-[90%] sm:w-[70%] top-0 right-0 bottom-0 z-10 overflow-hidden`}>
  <div className="border-b-2">
    <div className="flex justify-between items-center mb-2 mt-4">
      <div>
        {props.totalCartProducts > 0 ? (
          <h2 className="text-xl font-bold mx-5">
            Carrito de compras ({props.totalCartProducts}{" "}
            {props.totalCartProducts > 1 ? "productos" : "producto"})
          </h2>
        ) : (
          <h2 className="text-xl font-bold mx-5">Carrito de compras</h2>
        )}
      </div>
      <div className="flex justify-end">
        <img
          src={close}
          onClick={props.toggleCart}
          className="w-10 h-10 mx-5 object-contain cursor-pointer"
          alt="Close"
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div className="flex flex-col flex-grow overflow-y-auto">
    {cartProductElements}
  </div>
  <div className={`${props.totalCartProducts ? "" : "hidden"} border-t-2 mb-auto`}>
    <div className="flex flex-col sm:flex-row gap-2 sm:gap-0 sm:items-center px-5 my-2 justify-between">
      <h3 className="text-lg font-semibold">Total: ${total.toFixed(2)}</h3>
      <button className="flex justify-center items-center gap-2 px-4 pt-3 pb-2 bg-[#25D366] font-semibold rounded-lg text-sm hover:bg-[#128C7E]" onClick={checkout}>
        Continuar compra por WhatsApp
        <img src={whatsapp} alt='whatsappLogo' className='h-5 w-5 mb-1'></img>
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

    </div>
  )
```

This code is the return statement of the CartMenu component, which is utilized by the Products component. The latter component, when the CartMenu is displayed, makes the page fixed because I don't want it to be scrollable below the shopping cart menu.

[image]

However, on mobile devices, when the page is fixed, the browser takes up more space than it does on a scrollable page. As a result, this part of the browser UI covers the button at the bottom of the screen. I've tried adjusting various CSS properties and using media queries, but I'm still encountering this issue.

How to resolve this problem?

Comment: From a very quick glance at this it looks like it might be a CSS-related problem, but I don't see any CSS snippet provided. Can you add it please?

Comment: I don't think that is a CSS-related problem
This is App.css:
``@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Hind&display=swap');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@800&display=swap');

@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

body {
  font-family: 'Hind', sans-serif;
}

h1, h2, h3 {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}

.no-arrows::-webkit-inner-spin-button,
.no-arrows::-webkit-outer-spin-button {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  margin: 0;
}

.no-arrows[type=number] {
  -moz-appearance: textfield;
} ``

Comment: Im sorry, im new in StackOverflow, you can reproduce the problem in https://serramat.vercel.app/ and click the button 'Arma tu presupuesto' then add some item in the cart. You will see that in the developer tools the button is visible in all screen sizes, but then if you visit the site in a mobile phone the UI of the browser covers the button on the bottom of the page. 

If you want to see the code this is the github page: https://github.com/NachoG2000/serramat (Products.jsx and CartMenu.jsx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think You can see the green area under the adress box.
The button is not hidden and is under that.

[image: See Blue Area]

I think the reason of this you use the class `h-[100vh] ... overflow-hidden`

Your CartMenu component is higher than screen height, and set `overflow-hidden`. So you cannot see the button.
Firstly, you need to check the height of the render area of `cartProductElements`.

[image]

Secondly, You need to spot `flex-col sm:flex-row` classes. If you want to set `flex-col` as default and only set `flex-row` at `sm`, please set `flex-row md:flex-col`.
I hope you fix your error with my anwer.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me! The issue was in the h-[100vh] class, I solved the problem by using useEffect and an event listener for every resize of the screen and change the height of that element every time I open the CartMenu. I wouldn't have solved it without your help. You are great! <3

Comment: I am new in stackoverflow, too. I joind last month. I am very happy you solved your provlem with my answer. I hope you will get a good result in your development. Best Regards.